# Chinese remainder theorem in a regular category

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove a Chinese remainder theorem for regular categories (if this is possible). I'm stuck with the following question, which is really easy to answer positively in the set-theoretical case:

> Given congruences $R,S$ such that $SR = \top_A$ (the biggest relation
>   on $A$) on an object $A$ and respective quotients $e_1 : A \to A/R$,
>   $e_2 : A\to A/S$, is the morphism $$e := (e_1, e_2) : A\to A/R\times A/S$$ a regular epi?

The condition "$SR = \top_A$" is equivalent to saying that $(R_1\circ p_2, S_2\circ p_1)$ is a regular epi, where the upper left corner in the following diagram is a pullback:

[image]

But I don't see how to get anything useful from this.

Comment: I've a problem with your notation. By $(R_1 p_2, S_1 p_1)$ you mean an arrow $P\to A\times A$?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Yes, the one given by the universal property of the product $A\times A$.

Comment: And that's precisely $(R_1 p_2, S_1,p_1)$ that you want, not $(R_1 p_2, S_2,p_1)$ or $(R_2 p_2, S_1,p_1)$. Sorry if it seems a dumb question, I'm trying to see if I can say something meaningful :)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian The relation $SR$ is the image of $(R_1p_2, S_2p_1)$ (this does not depend on the choice of the pullback). Since the image is $\top_A$ that means that arrow is a regular epi. I don't know whether it is even a good idea to start this problem like this (there is no reference for this that I know of).

Comment: whoops, wrong index

Comment: I suspect the problem would be much easier if you instead sought to show that $e$ is the quotient map for a *specific* congruence. And you'd have a more useful result to boot. (and if it goes how I expect it to, it suggests there's a natural thing you can say about arbitrary $R,S$, akin to the more general form of the usual CRT)

Comment: @Hurkyl The kernel congruence $R_e$ of $e$ is $R\wedge S$ (this is the first half of the theorem). Showing $e$ is a quotient for that relation amounts to showing: for every $q : A \to Q$ such that $R\wedge S \leq R_q$ there is a unique morphism $u : A/R\times A/S \to Q$ such that $q = ue$. - I don't see how this is easier to show... - if I show that $e$ is a regular epi by any other means then it still follows that is the quotient of $R\wedge S$ (since a regular epi is always the quotient of its kernel congruence).

Comment: There are several (binary) operations $(f,g)\mapsto f\bullet g, \langle f,g\rangle,\dots$ on arrows of a category that preserve, or dualize, the fact that an arrow lies in a class of an orthogonal factorization system. Is it possible to deduce that the arrow $ c: A\to A/R\times A/S$ is a regular epi from the fact that there are regular epis $e_1, e_2$ such that $e_1\bullet e_2=c$, or $\langle e_1,e_2\rangle=c$, or...?

Comment: (of course, I'm using the fact that a regular category is basically a nice category endowed with $(RegEpi, Mono)$-factorization)

Comment: @StefanPerko: You can also define maps $X/\Theta \to Y/\Phi$ by giving maps $X \to Y$ and $\Theta \to \Phi$ making the relevant squares commute: i.e. a natural transformation of coequalizer diagrams gives a map of coequalizers.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Not sure what you mean. Regular epis are stable under composition, pullbacks and hence binary products. They are not stable under the $(\_,\_)$ operation.

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm aware. I have no idea at which point I can use $SR = \top$ though.

Comment: I don't mean the $(\_,\_)$ operation, but instead something like [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Joyal-Tierney+calculus)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Sorry. I don't know how to apply this here at all.

Comment: Did you managed in the end to prove the CRT for regular categories? If not, why not? If you did, I'd really like to see it (if possible, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
Consider the diagram
\begin{CD}A  @>{e_2}>> A/S \\
@V{e_1}VV  @VV{\tau_2}V \\
A/R  @>>{\tau_1}> 1
\end{CD}
and denote $\tau_A$ the unique arrow $A\to 1$, which is the diagonal of this square. Then by Proposition 2.2 in the paper "Some remarks on Mal'tsev and Goursat categories", the induced arrow to the pullback (or in this case, product) $A/R\times A/S$ is a regular epimorphism if and only if $\tau_1^{o} \tau_2=e_1e_2^{o}$. Now since $R=e_1^{o}e_1$, $S=e_2^{o}e_2$ and $\top_A=\tau_A^{o}\tau_A$, we have
$$e_1^{o}e_1e_2^{o}e_2=\tau_A^{o}\tau_A=e_1^{o}\tau_1^{o}\tau_2e_2;$$
composing with $e_1$ on the left and $e_2$ on the right gives us
$$e_1e_1^{o}e_1e_2^{o}e_2e_2^{o}=e_1e_1^{o}\tau_1^{o}\tau_2e_2e_2^{o}.$$
Now $e_1$ and $e_2$ are regular epimorphisms, so we have $e_1e_1^{o}=id_A=e_2e_2^{o}$, and thus $e_1e_2^{o}=\tau_1^{o}\tau_2$.

Note : the proof above is more or less the same as the one of Theorem 5.2 in the paper I mentioned.

Comment: Nice answer, very "clean". - (not the question but:) do you happen to know wether the existence of a terminal object is essential?

Comment: @StefanPerko I'm not sure. You need the maximal relation $\top_A$ to be the kernel pair of some arrow $A\to B$; if that's the case, then the theorem I mentioned gives you a regular epi $A\to A/R\times_B A/S$, but I'm not sure this pullback would necessarily be the product $A/R\times A/S$. But regular categories are finitely complete, so they should have a terminal object...